# How to set colors for entire application in on place instead of doing that on every SubPage.xaml in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Don't ask me why, but I thought only `<ContentPage>` can have `<ContentPage.Resources>`.

So I had a bunch of color setters and what not in almost **every** XAML page like this:

```xaml
       <ContentPage.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#000" />
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="#20b8a2" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPage">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#231f20" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#f7f7f7" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#f7f7f7" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#0089c1" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#f7f7f7" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
            </Style>
       </ContentPage.Resources>
```

So how to change all main colors in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of having resources in every Solution/App/Views/SubPage.xaml file there is obviously an outermost XAML file in general projects root Solution/App/App.xaml where you can simply set these resources for entire application.

```xaml
<Application ...>
       <Application.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#20b8a2</Color> <!-- turqoise -->
            <Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">#0089c1</Color> <!-- blue -->
            <Color x:Key="TertiaryColor">#ef569f</Color> <!-- pink -->
            <Color x:Key="ThemeExtremeColor">#000000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ThemeMainColor">#231f20</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ThemeLighterColor">#333333</Color>
            <Color x:Key="TextColor">#f7f7f7</Color>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ThemeExtremeColor}" />
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPage">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ThemeMainColor}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ThemeMainColor}" />
            </Style>
            <!--<Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ThemeMainColor}" />
            </Style>-->
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
            </Style>
       </Application.Resources>
       ....
</Application>
```

Now `"{StaticResource TextColor}"` can be used anywhere in XAML.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, which will help more people .

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Had to wait 2 days to be allowed to accept.